# Angular2: binding to input radio name doesn't work

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

In Angular2, one-way binding to the name attribute for a group of radio inputs doesn't work. For example:

```
<div [ngFormModel]="form">
  <input type="radio" [name]="varName" [id]="id1" ngControl="r1">
  <input type="radio" [name]="varName" [id]="id2" ngControl="r2">
  <input type="radio" [name]="varName" [id]="id3" ngControl="r3">
</div>
```

When loading the page, name is not an attribute on any of those radio inputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess what @Schippie wrote was correct. Use

```
[attr.name]="name"
```

instead of

```
[name]="name"
```

(his Plunker had a few issues)

[**Plunker example**](http://plnkr.co/edit/MNWFVGMaTQZSllNpDT4f)

Comment: Jup sorry was before dinner and i discovered it as well. Corrected the mistakes. One thing that is confusing though for people who just start using angular is that using `[name]="variable"` works on some elements in some conditions yet not always. So it seems much saver to always use `[attr.name]`. If you want it to show up on the element as well

Comment: That's not necessarily an Angular issue. Some properties (like `htmlFor` of the `label` element) don't have the same name as the attribute (`for`) they are reflected to. What is caused by Angular is that sometimes there are directives applied to elements that have an input with the same name as attributes, but these are not reflected to the attributes without using `[attr.name]`, but that is for performance reasons. Updating attributes is expensive because they change the DOM and can even cause rerendering.

Comment: I expect Angular to provide IDE support to be able to see if directives are applied eventually. Lots of design decisions were made to be able to provide great IDE support.

Comment: I honestly except Jetbrains with Webstorm to provide great support going forwards. Just wish they would hurry up and get the typescript tooling fixed as it still not on par with the Visual studio code editor which I currently use as it seems to be the one that reflects the tsc 100% accurately.

Answer (score 2):

If this works anything like the binding to the select property the name property will be set on the javascript dom element. Meaning while it does not display within the view it actually has been set on the HTMLElement.

Which is illustrated with the following plunk:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core'
import {ControlGroup, Control} from '@angular/common'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  providers: [],
  template: `
  <form [ngFormModel]="group">
      <input type="radio" [attr.name]="name" ngControl="test">
      <input type="radio" [attr.name]="name" ngControl="test2" ref-example>
      <input type="radio" [name]="name" ngControl="test3" ref-exampletwo>
      <p>using [attr.name]: {{example.name | json }}</p>
      <p>using [name]: {{exampletwo.name | json }}</p>
  </form>
  `
})
export class App {
  name: "test"
  group: ControlGroup

  constructor() {
    this.group = new ControlGroup({
      test: new Control(""),
      test2: new Control(""),
      test3: new Control("")
    })
  }
}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/xHkgb0BgPzZLwyFpTo1W?p=preview

What you actually want to do is the following:

`[attr.name]="name"`

This will set the property on the element.

Comment: `FORM_DIRECTIVES` and `FORM_PROVIDERS` are globally available and don't need to be provided. `...` in `directives` and `providers` is redundant. Why do you inject `FormBuilder` but then use `new ControlGroup(...)`. Just use `formBuilder.group(...)´ instead.

Comment: Your answer was deleted this is why I posted my own. I put some effort into it to make the Plunker work, therefore I don't want to delete it.

Comment: Good point about the form directives / providers was not aware of that normally i inject the providers within the bootstrap and the directives where needed. Good to know. Will modify the code to reflect that. And the formbuilder was just me lazily copying a constructor within my own code.